# asp.net core linux - CultureInfo get country code

Tags: c#, heroku, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am having issues validating country code on **Linux**. Following is the code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsCountryCodeValid("IN"));
    }

    public static bool IsCountryCodeValid(string countryCode)
    {
        return CultureInfo
            .GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
            .Select(culture => new RegionInfo(culture.Name))
            .Any(region => region.TwoLetterISORegionName == countryCode);
    }
}
```

It works on **Windows** and **macOS** returning **true**, but when the code runs on **Heroku** in a docker, the above code returns false.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: @JamieTaylor why this code is failing on Linux, and what fix can be used to make it work on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best guess (without knowing much about Linux) is that Linux cultures are *case-sensitive*. Since the "normal" way to specify culture is to use lower case letters and you are using upper case, this is probably why it doesn't work on Linux.

```
Console.WriteLine(IsCountryCodeValid("in"));
```

Second guess: The culture pack is not installed on the OS.