# Upgrade from .Net Core 2.2 to 3.1 changed culture detection on Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.Net Core app that I just upgraded from 2.2 to 3.1 as part of an effort to get to the latest version.

Everything is running correctly, except my numbers are now formatted differently.

Instead of showing a "$" in front of currencies, I now see "¤" (and I'm there are many other changes such as string comparison, etc).

It appears my Culture changed from `English (United States, Computer)` to  .

Where does the default culture come from? I've searched quite a bit and there are many topics about how to set the culture in code, etc. That's not what I'm looking for.

I want to know how .Net is determining a culture when you do nothing explicitly to set it since that his how the app was running previously. And more importantly, what would need to be adjusted to return the culture to how it was working previously without having to explicitly set it in code.

Below is the value of `locale`

```
$ locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

If I run a simple .Net program to print out the Culture, etc.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine($"CurrentCulture   = {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name}");
    Console.WriteLine($"CurrentUICulture = {CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{RegionInfo.CurrentRegion}");
}
```

...this is what I get

```
CurrentCulture   =
CurrentUICulture =
IV
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems no locales are set on systems. You can check the blogs and set locales.

[Configure Locales in Ubuntu](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Configure_Locales_in_Ubuntu)

[image]

**Related issue**

[asp.net core linux - CultureInfo get country code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577011/asp-net-core-linux-cultureinfo-get-country-code)

Comment: Do you have any idea why this issue didn't exhibit itself in .Net Core 2.2?

The only other thing I think that could have had an affect on this would be that I had restarted the system after installing the new .Net Core 3.1 runtime. That was the only package I had installed.