# .NET Core build OS affects json output encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I just noticed that our api responses were returning some invalid characters. In debugging this issue I realized that the invalid characters were only being returned if the project was built on linux runners on Azure DevOps.

Using a minimal api as example:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    return "Anulação";
});

app.Run();
```

Built on ubuntu-latest, if I run dotnet TestJson.dll on my Windows 11 machine I get (also ran this ubuntu publish output on my ubuntu 22.04 wsl and the results were the same):
[image: ubuntu prints strange chars]

Build on windows-latest, if I run dotnet TestJson.dll on my Windows 11 machine I get:
[image: windows prints correct chars]

In summary:

- project built on ubuntu-latest runners on Azure DevOps or ubuntu wsl on my Windows 11 machine results in the invalid chars being print
- project built on windows-latest runners on Azure DevOps or on my Windows 11 machine with either dotnet or Visual Studio prints the correct chars

I've also been directed to this [issue](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/762) on github actions (which are similar to Azure DevOps pipelines) and I've generated the pt_PT.UTF-8 locale files and I've set up all locale options as such (now my WSL is totaly in Portuguese and printing the correct chars such as ç and ã):

```
LANG=pt_PT.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=pt_PT.UTF-8
```

But still the api returns the invalid characters. I have looked at maybe configuring System.Text.Json Encoder but I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: What are the headers in the response? Is a character set specified there?

Comment: Response headers are the same in the linux build and windows build: Content-Type
text/plain; charset=utf-8, Date, Server and Transfer-Encoding. Response on the Linux build is 154 B and 152 B on the Windows one.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser or different fonts used in the browser?

Comment: What happens when you build on linux and run on linux? same behavior?

Comment: Nvm, you answered, is the same.

Comment: Still to double check, did you build and run on Linux? If there's no issue then target your build when build on Linux to windows runtime or vice versa. `dotnet publish "TestJson.csproj" -c Release -r linux-x64 -o d:/app/publish --no-self-contained`

Comment: Secondary, this looks like an encoding issue, not a build or runtime, instead of declaring string read the value from a file, then UTF-8 value is isolated from the build context.

Comment: Yes, I built and ran on Linux, the first screenshot comment mentions that I ran the linux build on my ubuntu WSL. Also tried Edge and Chrome instead of just firefox and the result was the same. Also published on WSL with -r win-x64 and the results were the same.

Comment: I know your have check the locale files, pls try to [read my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74918588/7687666) and follow the suggestions try again. You also can click the link inside my answer to check more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After two days of debugging and testing various combinations, what fixed it was setting the encoding on the *.cs files of my solution to "UTF-8". They were in "Western European" by default on my installation. I guess that's why building on Windows worked and Linux not (maybe Linux does not know this encoding).

I used VS2022 with **Tools->Customize->Commands**, **Menu bar: File** and then added the command "*Advanced Save Options*" to my File menu list. Then I was able to choose the encoding for saving the file.

After this change the problem was fixed.